# Creating trigger in oracle for preventing duplicate keys before inserting cmd

Tags: oracle, triggers, primary-key, sql-insert

I am trying to create a trigger in oracle which will detect a duplicate inseted primary key and will rename a new key by adding a prefix char for example 'P_'.
If somebody know the elegant solution for this problem, I will glad to see the answer :).

I started to write smth like this:

```
create or replace 
TRIGGER t1_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON T1
DECLARE selected_id varchar2(10);
BEGIN
  SELECT id INTO selected_id FROM T1 WHERE id = :new.id;
  IF (selected_id NOT NULL)
  THEN INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('p_');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: what would you do if you already had records with `id = 200` and `id = p_200` and were trying to insert a new record with `id=200`?

Comment: I already have thought about this issue, I just trying to make smth simple and not to take this into account, it's a college assignment and so i have a limits in implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elegant way would be to use an autoincrementing sequence as primary key. For more information check [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php) or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6015.htm).

Another approach would be to use the [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm)-statement. This way you could check for the existence of a duplicate key and if it exists, rename the old key to something else or adjust the key you are inserting accordingly.

Theoretically you also could do the following, but it's really not a good idea:

```
create or replace 
TRIGGER t1_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON T1
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
cursor c1 is select id from t1 where id = :new.id;
BEGIN
  for i in c1 loop
        :new.id := 'p_' || :new.id;
    end loop;
END;
```

**For clearification**: you would only append more than one 'p_' to your key if you only have multiple instances of your key already. The cursor is just for the case that your select statement will return zero or more than 1 row.

Comment: You'd get a no-data-found exception rather than a null value; but I think you'd also get a mutating table error from trying to select from the table that's being inserted into. (I'm not sure off-hand if the PK would report a constraint violation before the trigger even fires, I might try to test that).

Comment: TBH I didn't check the query for functionality as I kinda expected a working solution. I thought Ataman was just looking for some improvements. You are right, it wouldn't work that way. I will delete that part of my answer. But I don't think you'ld get a mutating table error as you are not inserting into the table but only adjusting the value that will be inserted. Not sure though.

Comment: Thanks :). I understood that might be a great solution to use an autoincremeanting sequence as a primary key.